# Group by and bring back value in first row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have query

```
SELECT   ID,  TIME,  PRICE,   QTY
FROM myTable
```

that returns:

```
ID             TIME             PRICE   QTY
1295179228  1/29/2015 20:59:37  15.24   1112
1295179228  1/29/2015 20:59:37  15.23   2
1295179228  1/29/2015 20:59:38  15.28   22
1295179228  1/29/2015 20:59:38  15.27   1800
```

I am then using group by to return the min time, average price and sum of qty BUT I also want to return the first time

```
SELECT   ID, t2.name, min(TIME) as MinTIME, avg(PRICE) as AVGPrice, sum( QTY) as SUMQTY
FROM myTable t inner join table2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
group by ID, t2.name
```

But how do I add a column in that group by query above that will also return the first PRICE. In that case that would be 15.24

I have been googling and I see oracle has FIRST() and FIRST_VALUE() functions but I could not get them to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Umm,isnt MIN(TIME) already doing that?Also first in rapport with what?Without ORDER BY results might change at any time.

Comment: HI Mihai I made an error. I mean I want the first PRICE not first TIME. Please see edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "first price" means "price with the earliest time"

`min(price) keep (dense_rank first order by time)`

Comment: be here now - your solution seems to work. And I can change min() to average but   What I would really like to do is not the first price but the weighted average of the price for the first second so in the above data there are 2 rows for 20:59:37 and I would like to return the weighted average price in that second so:  (15.24*1112 +15.23*2)/sum(1112+2) = 15.23998.  Can that be done with your method?

Comment: @user3022875 `sum(price*qty) keep(dense_rank first order by time) / sum(qty) keep(dense_rank first order by time)`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT ID,"TIME",PRICE,QTY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TIME ASC) as rn
FROM t)
SELECT ID, min("TIME") as MinTIME, avg(PRICE) as AVGPrice, sum( QTY) as SUMQTY,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN PRICE ELSE 0 END) as FirstPrice
FROM CTE
group by ID
```

Comment: I get an error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. Can you explain what cte is and what "t" is and how the max(case.. works?

Comment: @user3022875 Hey t stands for yourtable,CTEs are a temprary filter sort of,I use it to put a row number on every id ordered by time,so I can select those with row number(rn) 1.

Comment: ok I wonder Why I get that error "FROM keyword not found where expected."  I replaced "t" with my table name. Do i need to replace "rn" with anything?

Comment: @user3022875 Try it now and use double quotes for TIME,it`s a reserved word

Comment: Ok It works but in my real example I have 2 joins in the second Select statement. Do I need to include them in the first select statement and remove them from the second one?   Well...All the field I need are only from one table so can I put all fields in the first Select then when I join refer to CTE  instead of the table name?

Comment: @user3022875 Edit your question with your full query,Yeah,you can JOIN with the CTE.

Comment: Mihai -- I have edited the query. What I would really like to do is not the first price but the weighted average of the price for the first second so in the above data there are 2 rows for 20:59:37 and I would like to return the weighted average price in that second so:  (15.24*1112 +15.23*2)/sum(1112+2) = 15.23998.  Can that be done?

Comment: @user3022875 It\`s a bit impolite to keep changing the requirements ask another question and I`ll take a look tomorrow if nobody answers.

Comment: Apologies Mihai for the changes but I just noticed the duplicate rows so I needed a weighted average.  I am not sure what way could work so I responded to the other poster. Thank you for your help.